# related list for custom objects

Tags: salesforce

I have 2 different custom objects and there is a look up relations between the two. Can I display the related activities on one custom object on the other? Is there a way to do this in salesforce?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
For this purpose you need a Visual Force page and a few apex code.
Learn Visual Force by the following links:

- [Intro](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce)
- [Documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index.htm)
- [Performance](http://media.developerforce.com/pdfs/salesforce_visualforce_best_practices.pdf)

Your task is more basically task in VF development.